# Wordpress permission issue

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having a weird issue that is stopping me from automatically updating wordpress and installing new plugins from the admin panel.

For example, I get a notification at the top that says:

```
Sorry, but you do not have the correct permissions to update the Contact Form 7 plugin. Contact the administrator of this site for help on getting the plugin updated.
Please contact the administrator of this site for help.
```

I've set the permissions to `wp-content` to `755` and all it's enclosed folders. I've never had this problem before. Any one know what to do?

Answer (score 3):

Well, I've never had this issue before. But after digging into `wp-config.php` I found both:

`define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true);`
`define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS',true);`

All I did was change true to false, and everything works as normal.